# Wrong use of forward declaration?

Tags: c++, class, oop, declaration, forward

Sometimes I use foreward declaration for nested classes:

```
class A;

class B
{
  private:
    A* object_A;
  public:
    B(){}
};
```

The question: What happens if I now use forward declaration of class `B` (`B` is declared and defined at this point) for the useage in class `C`? Does this cause any problems with class `B`, because it is defined (with implementation of methods etc.) but is used with forward declaration for class `C`? Does the syntax `class B;` in the following code-snippet overwrites somehow the previous declared, defined and implemented class `B`?

```
class B;

class C
{
  private:
    B* object_B;
  public:
    C(){}
};
```

Comment: Why don't you try and tell us.

Comment: Seems to work. But maybe I dont see all consequences.

Comment: There aren't any 'wrong uses of a forward declaration'. If the compiler needs the complete type *as well*, it will tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the syntax class B; in the following code-snippet overwrites somehow the previous declared, defined and implemented class B?

Forward declarations are not about overwriting. It is just giving hint to the compiler that the type definition is implemented somewhere. For user defined pointer types, compiler does not require the definition but needs to know what is the type of the object.